# What would be the best way to cycle through an array of elements from HTML in order to use 2 separate tag names in the order they came?

Tags: python, json, selenium

Not really sure how to word this question properly, but I'm basically playing around with python and using Selenium to scrape a website and I'm trying to create a JSON file with the data.

Here's the goal I'm aiming to achieve:

```
{
 "main1" : {
    "sub1" : "data",
    "sub2" : "data",
    "sub3" : "data",
    "sub4" : "data"
  },
  "main2" : {
    "sub1" : "data",
    "sub2" : "data",
    "sub3" : "data",
    "sub4" : "data"
  }
}
```

The problem I'm facing at the moment is that the website has no indentation or child elements. It looks like this (but longer and actual copy, of course):

```html
<h3>Main1</h3>
<p>Sub1</p>
<p>Sub2</p>
<p>Sub3</p>
<p>Sub4</p>
<h3>Main2</h3>
```

Now I want to iterate through the HTML in order to use the `<h3>` tags as the parent ("Main" in the JSON example) and `<p>` tags as the children(sub[num]). I'm new to both python and Selenium, so I may have done this wrong, but I've tried using `items.find_elements_by_tag_name('el')` to separate two, but I don't know how to put them back together in the order that they originally came.

I then tried looping through all the elements and separating the tags using `if (item.tag_name == "el"):` loops. This works perfectly when I print the results of each loop, but when it comes to putting them together in a JSON file, I have the same issue as the previous method where I cannot seem to get the 2 to join. I've tried a few variations and I either get key errors or only the last item in the loop gets recorded.

Just for reference, here's the code for this step:

```py
items = browser.find_element_by_xpath(
    '//*[@id="main-content"]') #Main Content

itemList = items.find_elements_by_xpath(".//*")
statuses = [
    "Status1",
    "Status2",
    "Status3",
    "Status4"
]

for item in itemList: #iterate through the HTML
    if (item.tag_name == "h3"): #Separate H3 Tags
        main = item.text
        print("======================================")
        print(main)
        print("======================================")

    if (item.tag_name == 'p'): #Separate P tags
        for status in statuses: 
            if(status in item.text): #Filter P tags to only display info that contains words in the Status array
                delimeters = ":", "(", "See"
                regexPattern = "|".join(map(re.escape, delimeters))
                zoneData = re.split(regexPattern, item.text)
                
                #Split P tags into separate parts
                sub1 = zoneData[0] 
                sub2 = zoneData[1].translate({ord('*'): None})
                sub3 = zoneData[2].translate({ord(")"): None})

                print(sub1)
                print(sub2)
                print(sub3)
```

The final option I've decided to try is to try going through all the HTML again, but using `enumerate()` and using the element's IDs and including all the tags between the 2 IDs, but I'm not really sure what my plan of action is with this just yet.

In general, the last option seems a bit convoluted and I'm pretty certain there's a simpler way to do this. What would you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my idea, but I didn't do the data part, you can add it later.

I assume that there's no duplicate in main name, or else you will lose some info.

```py
items = browser.find_element_by_xpath(
    '//*[@id="main-content"]') #Main Content
itemList = items.find_elements_by_xpath(".//p|.//h3") # only finds h3 or p

def construct(item_list):
    current_main = ''
    final_dict: dict = {}
    for item in item_list:
        if item.tag_name == "h3":
            current_main = item.text
            final_dict[current_main] = {} # create empty dict inside main. remove if you want to update the main dict
        if item.tag_name == "p":
            p_name = item.text
            final_dict[current_main][p_name] = "data"
    return final_dict
```